# Pandoc error while converting .md to .docx file

Tags: runtime-error, pandoc, virtualalloc

While attempting to convert `.md` to `docx` file using command line:

```sh
pandoc CustomerChurn_predict.md -s -o churn.docx
```

I got following error:

> pandoc: getMBlocks: VirtualAlloc MEM_COMMIT failed: The paging file is too small for this operation to complete.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a memory allocation error.

See: [VirtualAlloc MEM_COMMIT and MEM_RESERVE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26029374/virtualalloc-mem-commit-and-mem-reserve)

Pandoc may use rather large amount of memory for conversion.

See also [Pandoc's FAQ](https://pandoc.org/faqs.html):

> Pandoc sometimes uses too much memory. **How can I limit the memory used by pandoc?**
>
> `pandoc +RTS -M30m -RTS` will limit heap memory to 30MB. When converting a document requires more than this, an out of memory error will be issued.

The error message reports the limitation of your page file:

> The paging file is too small for this operation to complete.

Can you increase the page file size?

Comment: My file cant be changed since the solution of the problem statement cant be more than what i resolved. So is it possible to limit the size to lesser of about 5MB?